# I get a Bad request Status Code 400 when I am trying to consume a REST API online using C#

Tags: c#, rest

I am working with REST APIs and trying to connect to a REST API online that I can get to fine via the browser but when I try with some simple code, it is failing:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1");

        try
        {
            var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{response.StatusCode} - {response.ToString()}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }
```

The response message I get is the following:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-authentication, X-client
  Host-Header: c2hhcmVkLmJsdWVob3N0LmNvbQ==
  Pragma: no-cache
  Referrer-Policy: 
  Response: 400
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2020 10:38:39 GMT
  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=a8474e93077d190fe6bcdcb1ae1cbd42; path=/
  Set-Cookie: ezoadgid_133674=-1; Path=/; Domain=restapiexample.com; Expires=Fri, 10 Apr 2020 11:08:39 UTC
  Set-Cookie: ezoref_133674=; Path=/; Domain=restapiexample.com; Expires=Fri, 10 Apr 2020 12:38:39 UTC
  Set-Cookie: ezoab_133674=mod58-c; Path=/; Domain=restapiexample.com; Expires=Fri, 10 Apr 2020 12:38:39 UTC
  Set-Cookie: active_template::133674=pub_site.1586515119; Path=/; Domain=restapiexample.com; Expires=Sun, 12 Apr 2020 10:38:39 UTC
  Server: nginx/1.16.0
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Vary: User-Agent
  Vary: X-APP-JSON
  X-Ezoic-Cdn: Miss
  X-Middleton-Response: 400
  X-Sol: pub_site
  Content-Length: 75
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe the service was just down?

I just tried this via POSTMAN and I got the 400 error you mentioned.  
I then tried via Chrome and got the same error.

But, I then refreshed and it was working!  Both in Chrome and POSTMAN!

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith thanks for the response, I got an error via Chrome every now and then too, so maybe it is just that REST API. I will try creating a local REST API to re-test that bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the REST API itself, because when I used the following REST API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 it worked fine.